# Length prefixed strings in C

Tags: c, strings

In want to implement length prefixed strings in C (not null terminated), with some idiosyncrasies: malloc is prohibited, memory efficiency is important, each string (except for literal-backed ones) is modifiable and can change its length, but it has a fixed (at declaration) allocated length (maximum 255), C code is generated by a code generator.  I want this to work on as many architectures and C compilers as possible.

Suppose I do the following:

```
typedef struct PLS { 
   uint8_t maxlen; 
   uint8_t curlen; 
   char buf[1];  // actual allocated size is in maxlen 
} PLS ;
```

Then I could declare, say

```
  struct {
    ...
    PLS s1;   // real allocated size: 100
    char s1buf[99];
    PLS s2;  // real allocated size: 64 
    char s2buf[63];
    ...
    };

   // initialization:
   mystruct.s1.maxlen=100;
   mystruct.s1.curlen=0;
   mystruct.s2.maxlen=64;
   mystruct.s2.curlen=0;

   // PLS library:

   void PLS_copy(PLS *to,PLS *from) {
       int tc = from-> curlen; // chars to copy
       if(tc > to->maxlen) tc = to->maxlen;
       memcpy(to->buf,from->buf,tc);
   }
```

Does this look ok? Any pitfalls? Would some compiler give warnings?
I believe that data structure alignment should not padding between `s1` and `s1buf`, but even then it should work, right?

For literals, if I want to avoid a duplication of allocated chars, things seem trickier (remember, though, that code is machine-generated). Would this be objectionable?

```
 // static declaration of literal "hello" (5 chars) trailing null byte wasted
 char lit1[] = "\x05\x05hello"; 
// can the above be casted to PLS? (I won't modif it, I swear)
 PLS * lit1Pls = &(PLS)(lit1);  // smells funny, though...
```

Comment: Accessing beyond an array of length `1` causes undefined behaviour. You seem unaware , but the C standard is very strict about array bounds. The length-1-and-read-off-the-end hack that was "popular" in the 1980s was never legal and modern compilers will break the code. Instead you could use the *flexible array member*. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad) or browse that tag for other examples.

Comment: Minor idea: `void PLS_copy()` could return `int` to indicate if the copy was completely successful.

Answer (score 2):

## Copy function improvements

Your copy function could be better:

> ```
>    void PLS_copy(PLS *to,PLS *from) {
>        int tc = from-> curlen; // chars to copy
>        if(tc > to->maxlen) tc = to->maxlen;
>        memcpy(to->buf,from->buf,tc);
>    }
> ```

1. You could use `const` on your `from` argument.
2. You never update the length of the `to` string.  I'm assuming this is like a `strcpy`, so the `to` string should have its length set to the length that you just copied.

Here is how I would write it:

```
   void PLS_copy(PLS *to, const PLS *from)
   {
       uint8_t bytesToCopy = from->curlen;

       if (bytesToCopy > to->maxlen)
           bytesToCopy = to->maxlen;
       memcpy(to->buf, from->buf, bytesToCopy);
       to->curlen = bytesToCopy;
   }
```

## Flexible array member

I agree with the comment by M.M about using flexible array members instead of `buf[1]`:

```
typedef struct PLS { 
   uint8_t maxlen; 
   uint8_t curlen; 
   char buf[];  // actual allocated size is in maxlen 
} PLS;

struct {
    ...
    PLS s1;   // real allocated size: 100
    char s1buf[100];
    PLS s2;  // real allocated size: 64 
    char s2buf[64];
    ...
};
```

Also, you could use a macro to help declare these fields.  Something like this:

```
#define PLS_FIELD(name, length)  \
    PLS name;                    \
    char name##buf[length]
```

Then you could define your struct as:

```
struct {
    ...
    PLS_FIELD(s1, 100);
    PLS_FIELD(s2, 64);
    ...
};
```

## Casting literal

For your literal casting, I would do this:

```
char lit1[] = "\x05\x05hello";
const PLS *lit1Pls = (const PLS *) lit1;
```

The `const` keyword here will prevent you from writing to the literal.  And the cast I used is simpler than the one you used.  I don't see anything objectionable about doing this.